# NSMutableArray Setter and Getter Methods

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to make an FoodCourt Application. I have 3 MutableArray in AppDelegate.h

**// This are declaration and Getter and Setter methods for array.**

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray* NameArray;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray* QtyArray;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray* KGArray;


-(NSMutableArray*)GetNameNSO;
-(NSMutableArray*)GetQtyNSO;
-(NSMutableArray*)GetKGNSO;
-(void)setNameArray:(NSMutableArray*)NameArray;
-(void)setQtyArray:(NSMutableArray*)QtyArray;
-(void)setKGArray:(NSMutableArray*)KGArray;
```

I have Implemented Getter and Setter methods in AppDelegate.m

**Appdelegate.m**

```
@synthesize NameArray =_NameArray;
@synthesize KGArray =_KGArray;
@synthesize QtyArray=_QtyArray;


-(NSMutableArray*)GetNameNSO
{
    if(_NameArray == nil)
    {
        _NameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSLog(@"%@ GetName FROM HELPER",_NameArray);
        return _NameArray;
    }
    else
    {
        return _NameArray;
    }


}
-(NSMutableArray*)GetQtyNSO
{
    if(_QtyArray == nil)
    {
        _QtyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSLog(@"%@ GetQTY FROM HELPER",_QtyArray);
        return _QtyArray;
    }
    else
    {
        return _QtyArray;
    }
}
-(NSMutableArray*)GetKGNSO
{
   if(_KGArray == nil)
   {
        _KGArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSLog(@"%@ GetKG FROM HELPER",_KGArray);
        return _KGArray;
    }
    else
    {
        return _KGArray;
    }
}
-(void)setQtyArray:(NSMutableArray *)QtyArray{

    _QtyArray=QtyArray;
    NSLog(@"%@ SetQty FROM HELPER",_QtyArray);
}
-(void)setNameArray:(NSMutableArray *)NameArray
{
    _NameArray =NameArray;
    NSLog(@"%@ SetName FROM HELPER",_NameArray);
}
-(void)setKGArray:(NSMutableArray *)KGArray
{
    _KGArray =KGArray;
    NSLog(@"%@ SetKG FROM HELPER",_KGArray);
}
```

Setter Methods works fine as is it should. I am setting my values from FoodController.h in this setter methods and it give me Perfect log with all the values in method.

**FoodController.h**

```
AppDelegate *AppAdd;


AppAdd = [[AppDelegate alloc]init];

[AppAdd setNameArray:NameSegue];
[AppAdd setKGArray:KGQtySegue];
[AppAdd setQtyArray:QtySegue];
```

Above Code is called in **prepareForSegue** Method. after changing my application view i am trying to fetch this data from Getter method in OrderDetails.m But it give null or no value. I just don't understand why this methods do not work properly. Here's the code of OrderDetails.m file.

**OrderDetails.m**

```
AppDelegate *sc;

sc=[[AppDelegate alloc]init];

[DataName addObjectsFromArray:sc.GetNameNSO];
[DataQty addObjectsFromArray:sc.GetQtyNSO];
[DataQty addObjectsFromArray:sc.GetKGNSO];
```

I just don't understand Why this code is not working, Please Help me out! Thank you.

**New Code For Getting Array :**

```
AppDelegate *sc = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
sc=[[AppDelegate alloc]init];

[DataName addObjectsFromArray:sc.GetNameNSO];
[DataQty addObjectsFromArray:sc.GetQtyNSO];
[DataQty addObjectsFromArray:sc.GetKGNSO];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not create the object of App delegate. You should get it by below way.

```
AppDelegate *sc = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[DataName addObjectsFromArray:sc.GetNameNSO];
[DataQty addObjectsFromArray:sc.GetQtyNSO];
[DataQty addObjectsFromArray:sc.GetKGNSO];
```

Now, sc will have required values. Do not forget to import Appdelegate.h file into the orderdetails.m file.

Comment: I tried your method. still i am not getting any data.

Comment: @RajanPalaniya Please update your question with the new code you're trying

Comment: Can someone Elaborate it please? I just don't understand how that works. I am new to iOS programming.

Comment: See the code that you need to write. Do not alloc the appdelegate.